Solving the system $x-x^2=az^2$, $\;y-y^2=2xy+bz^2$, $\;1-z=2x+2\alpha y$ for $x$, $y$, $z$
I have the following system I need to solve:
$$\begin{align}
x-x^2 &=az^2 \\
y-y^2 &=2xy+bz^2 \\
1-z\phantom{^2}   &=2x+2\alpha y
\end{align}$$
where $a$, $b$, $\alpha$ are just constants.
I solved a special case when $b=0$ but it seems super tricky when $b \neq 0$. There are 16 general solutions due to Bezout.
Can it even be solved exactly?
The solution when $b=0$ is not exactly nice looking, so I assume the answers are a lot more horrible if $b \neq 0$ but I don't care as long as it can be done.
Thanks

WolframAlpha shows 5 solutions and with the last one having  $b\ne0$.   https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+x-x%5E2+%3Daz%5E2%2C+++++y-y%5E2+%3D2xy%2Bbz%5E2+%2C+++1-z++%3D2x%2B2+%5Calpha+y

@Moo can you tell me what software you used and how you did it? Would be useful for me to do myself as well

@Moo What was the intent of the problem composer?

@poetasis What was the intent of the problem composer?

@Moo Unless the source of the problem is a class in using computer software, it is unlikely that the problem composer intended that the problem be attacked by computer software.

The problem is just I need an answer for some research. But as long as I have an answer, the method is unimportant. In fact I never really thought it would be suitable to be tackled without a computer anyway

@Moo Could you provide a link to where you did it?

If all you need is an answer, here is the one Wolfram came up with where $,b\ne0.,$
\begin{align*}
\text{solve}\qquad x-x^2 &=az^2\ y-y^2 &=2xy+bz^2 \1-z, &=2x+2 \alpha y
\end{align*}
$$\text{answer}\qquad x = 0 ∧ y = 1 ∧ z = 0 ∧ α≈0.5 ∧ a b\ne0$$ Also  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x-x%5E2+%3Daz%5E2%2C+++++y-y%5E2+%3D2xy%2Bbz%5E2+%2C+++1-z++%3D2x%2B2+%5Calpha+y%2C++x+%3D+0+%E2%88%A7+y+%3D+1+%E2%88%A7+z+%3D+0+%E2%88%A7+%CE%B1%E2%89%880.5+%E2%88%A7+a+b%5Cne0

@Moo I tried, for about 20 minutes, to conjure an analytical solution, and failed.  However, I strongly suspect that an analytical solution exists.  That is, otherwise, the math problem would have no educational value, and would therefore be pointless.

@Moo Why did you delete your answer? When I said I just need an answer, I wanted a general solution in terms of a,b, and alpha.

Note. Value $z=0$ occurs only with $(x,y)=(0,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ (and these only if $\alpha=1/2$). Going forward, I'll assume $z\neq 0$.
Note 2. Throughout, I write $c$ for OP's $\alpha$.
Playing with a raw and complicated solution obtained through Mathematica's Solve[] function, I found that $x$ and $y$ really wants to be replaced by, say, $x\to(1+uz)/2$ and $y\to vz$; likewise, $c\to (1-d)/2$, with $d\neq0,-1$, removes a bit of notational clutter. With these, the system becomes
$$\begin{align}
(u^2 + 4a ) z^2 &= \phantom{-}1 \tag1 \\
v (u + v) &= -b \tag2 \\
u + v \phantom{)} &= \phantom{-}dv-1 \tag3
\end{align}$$
(where I divided $(2)$ and $(3)$ through by (non-zero!) $z^2$ and $z$). We see from $(3)$
$$u = v(d-1)-1 \tag{$\star$}$$
Substituting-in to $(2)$ gives
$$v(d v - 1) + b  = 0\tag{$\star\star$} \qquad\to\qquad v = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4bd}}{2d}$$
So we can consider $v$ to be known. Then, equating $u^2$ from from $(1)$ and $(3)$ implies
$$\frac{1-4az^2}{z^2} = (v(d-1)-1)^2 \qquad\to\qquad z = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{4a+(\,v(d-1)-1\,)^2}} \tag{$\star\star\star$}$$
So, to solve the system, we calculate $z$, then $y=vz$, then $x=(1+uz)/2$.
The sign choices in $(\star\star)$ and $(\star\star\star)$ are independent, given four solutions. $\square$

It's perhaps worth noting that
$$v (d - 1) - 1 = \frac{(1-c) \pm c \sqrt{1+4b(2c-1)}}{2c-1}$$
If $c$ were known to be constrained between $0$ and $1$, we could write, say, $c=\cos^2\theta$ for some $\theta$, so that this becomes
$$ \frac{\sin^2\theta \pm \cos^2\theta \sqrt{1+4b\cos2\theta}}{\cos2\theta} = \frac{\tan^2\theta \pm \sqrt{1+4b\cos2\theta}}{1-\tan^2\theta}$$
I wonder if this observation has any relevance to the underlying situation encoded in OP's system of equations.

As a bit of an origin story for this solution, I started simply by telling Mathematica
Solve[{x-x^2 == a z^2, y-y^2 == 2x y+b z^2, 1-z == 2x+2c y}, {x,y,z}]
The software dutifully churned-out four solutions, differing  only in a couple of signs. Cleaning-up a little, they have this form:
$$\begin{align}
z &= \phantom{\frac12+\;} m  \\[4pt]
y &= \phantom{\frac12+\;} m \cdot \frac{1 + \sigma_2 \sqrt{q}}{2 (1-2c)}\\[4pt]
x &= \frac12 + m\cdot \frac{r m^2 - s}{4 (1 - c) (1 - 2 c)}
\end{align}$$
where
$$\begin{align}
m &:= \sigma_1 \sqrt{\frac{p - 2\sigma_2 c(1-c) \sqrt{q}}{r}} \\[4pt]
p &:= 1 + 4 a - 2 c - 16 a c + 2 c^2 + 16 a c^2 - 4 b c^2 + 8 b c^3 \\
q &:= 1 - 4 b (1-2c) \\
r &:=1 + 8 a + 16 a^2 - 16 a c - 64 a^2 c + 16 a c^2 + 64 a^2 c^2 + 
 8 b c^2 - 32 a b c^2 + 64 a b c^3 + 16 b^2 c^4 \\
s &:= 3 + 4 a - 6 c - 16 a c + 4 c^2 + 16 a c^2 - 4 c^3 + 8 c^4
\end{align}$$
and signs $\sigma_1=\pm1$ and $\sigma_2=\pm1$ are chosen independently to give the four solutions.
That's an answer, but a bit of a mess. Being somewhat inclined to seek patterns in chaos, I looked for ways to streamline the expressions in hopes of simplifying the derivation. (Knowing how the equations arose would likely have helped with this.) Writing $x=(1+uz)/2$ and $y=vz$ (for $z\neq 0$) seemed fairly obvious (although perhaps not completely so: In the first version of this answer, I'd used simply $x=(1+u)/2$; no $z$). The appearances of $1-2c$ suggested replacing them with $d$ (although I'm now thinking that $c=\cos^2\theta$ may be better, provided $c$ is appropriately constrained).
These substitutions, and dividing through by $z\neq0$, led nicely to the simplified system $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$, which in turn admitted a straightforward solution via quadratics.

What general solution did you get to notice this? Do you know of any other software that can do similar things to this? I don’t have access to Mathematica currently unfortunately.
Also, how does it come to be that $y$ and $z$ are necessarily scalar multiples? Does the solution show this?

@Anonmath101: I've added some notes about how I went from Mathematica's messy solution to my own (now slightly improved). I'm afraid I don't have any alternative software recommendations to offer.

Presumably you mean $c$ in your asnwer to be $\alpha$, right?

@Anonmath101: "Presumably you mean $c$ in your asnwer to be $\alpha$, right?" ... Yes. Note 2 at the top says as much. :)

Apologies for missing that! I have started a chatroom with you if you would like to discuss where this problem came from?

@Anonmath101: I don't chat, but I would suggest that you to add the origins of the problem to the body of the question. More context is always helpful to readers (not only current ones, but the untold numbers who visit Math.SE in the future). .... Good luck with your research!
